# Users with different attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
type_choices = (
    ('A', 'User Type A'),
    ('B', 'User Type B'),
    ('C', 'User Type C'),
)
user_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                             choices=type_choices,
                             default='C')

class UserDetails(model.Model):
    type = models.OneToOneField('CustomUser')
    extra_info = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How would I make it so that each user has different fields? Examples. One has a available hours field. Another has an address field.

Or Would I do something like this?

```
class BaseUser(AbstractUser):
# all the common fields go here, for example:
email = models.EmailField(max_length=10,unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class StoreOwnerUser(BaseUser):
# All Store Owner specific attribute goes here
balance = models.some_balance_field()
stores_owned = models.some_stores_owned_field()

class Meta:
verbose_name = 'Store Owner'
```

And if this is the way to do it then: What would be specified as AUTH_USER_MODEL? Also at the time of login: user = authenticate(username = username, password = password). From which table (CustomerUser or StoreOwnerUser) would the authenticate function check from? Its okay I can make seperate login pages for each, but then how would  that be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be adding a diferent class for each type of user. Each new class would be in a OneToOneField with your main user profile.

After creating a new user in your views.py you could create the appropiate class of user based on the choices presented.

```
new_user = CustomUser.objects.create(user_type='desired_type')
if new_user.user_type == 'typeA':
  user_A.objects.create(CustomerUser=new_user,) # add desired fields
elif new_user.user_type == 'typeB':
  user_B.objects.create(CustomerUser=new_user,) # add desired fields
```

Comment: So for those classes it should be class TypeA(models.Model)... or should it be class TypeA(custombaseprofile)

Comment: TypeA(models.Model):
  CustomUser = models.OneToOneField('CustomUser')

Comment: for assigning a user to a field, since theres now mulitple profile classes would I still be able to use. user = get_object_or_404(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, pk=user_id)

Comment: Yes. And afterwards you could define a custom function where based on the type of user you could gather the appropiate profile (class).

Comment: Would that function be placed inside the CustomUser(AbstractUser) class?

Comment: You may. Also in the views.py script would be acceptable.

Comment: Would I need to use signals for the registration to properly work to make sure it doesnt register just a simple User like djangos default?